# Very simple string replace fails

Tags: java, replace

```
final String message =
                        "Please enter the following code in the password reset screen:\n" +
                                "\n"+
                                "{CODE} (((((" + codeStr + ")))))\n" +
                                "If you didn't ask for this code, or don't know what this e-mail is about, you can safely ignore it."
                                .replace("{CODE}", codeStr);
```

This results in

> Please enter the following code in the password reset screen: {CODE} (((((5RE2GT4FWH))))) If you didn't ask for this code, or don't know what this e-mail is about, you can safely ignore it.

How can such a simple replace not work? I thought that maybe the problem was that the two instances of `{CODE}` looked alike but were in fact composed of different characters, but I copy-pasted one over the other and it didn't fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are invoking the `replace()` only on the last `String` object: [`"If you didn't ask for this code, or don't know what this e-mail is about, you can safely ignore it."`].

Store it [the final `String`, before the `replace()`] to some temp variable and retry, or use parentheses.

Answer (score 5):

Asking is knowing:

```
final String message =
                    (
                            "Please enter the following code in the password reset screen:\n" +
                            "\n"+
                            "{CODE}" + codeStr + "\n" +
                            "If you didn't ask for this code, or don't know what this e-mail is about, you can safely ignore it."
                    )
                    .replace("{CODE}", codeStr);
```

Because of the lack of parentheses, replace was performed on the last part of the composed string first, and only then were the parts concatenated together.

Comment: I just like how you managed to answer your own question and now everyone is giving you free upvotes ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to call replace on the full string:

```
final String message =
        ("Please enter the following code in the password reset screen:\n" +
         "\n"+ "{CODE} (((((" + codeStr + ")))))\n" +
         "If you didn't ask for this code, or don't know what this e-mail is about, you can safely ignore it."
        ).replace("{CODE}", codeStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only calling `replace()` on the *last* String literal. You need brackets around the whole message, like this:

```
final String message =
    ("Please enter the following code in the password reset screen:\n" +
     "\n"+
     "{CODE} (((((" + codeStr + ")))))\n" +
     "If you didn't ask for this code, or don't know what this e-mail is about, you can safely ignore it."
     )
     .replace("{CODE}", codeStr);
```

Comment: I'm calling this a draw and gone on an upvote fest for everyone

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of solution that would benefit from upgrading this older Java code style to one that uses the (old, but newer than this) `java.util.Formatter`

```
final String message =
                        "Please enter the following code in the password reset screen:\n" +
                                "\n"+
                                "{CODE} (((((" + codeStr + ")))))\n" +
                                "If you didn't ask for this code, or don't know what this e-mail is about, you can safely ignore it."
                                .replace("{CODE}", codeStr);
```

Would then become

```
Formatter formatter = new Formatter(new StringBuilder, Locale.US);
final String message = formatter.format("Please enter the following code in the password reset screen:\n\n %s ((((( %s )))))\n", codeStr);
```